# Should extended Latin characters in urls (ü, ö, etc.) be percent-encoded as standard?

Tags: url, canonical-url, url-encoding

I'm putting together an English language site which contains its own German translation (don't worry, I've lived in Germany and I have a degree in Germanic and Slavonic Studies, it's proper German...).

I am wondering what the best practice is regarding extended Latin characters in URLs.

If I have a URL like:

```
https://example.com/fußgängerbrücke/
```

Am I better to link to it internally as:

- a) `/fußgängerbrücke/`
- b) `/fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke/`
- c) `/fussgaengerbruecke/`

I have no problem doing any of the above and I am quite happy to use `.htaccess` `mod_rewrite` if and where necessary to ensure that variants all `301` to the correct canonical page.

On that note, a secondary question: which format (if different) should I be using for the `<link rel="canonical">` in the `<head>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See how the Wikipedia handles this: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke"/>
```

Comment: Hah! Very smart approach. I never thought of that. Yes, it's `/fu%C3%9Fg%C3%A4ngerbr%C3%BCcke/` in both internal links and `rel="canonical"`. Thank you!